# Is there any way that I can solve second order linear differential equation with functions as coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I have a equation

$\frac{1}{t}r'(t)+r''(t)=0$, where $t=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

I was trying to find out solution by inspection.

One solution is constant, which is trivial.

But, How can I actually solve this without guess-work

Thnaks!

Answer (score 1):

Put $s=r'$ and the equation transforms into $$\frac{1}{t}s+s'=0$$

This is the same as $$-\frac{1}{t}=(\ln(s(t)))'$$

So, $\ln(s(t))=-\ln(t)+C$, i.e. $r'(t)=s(t)=e^{-\ln(t)+C}=\frac{e^C}{t}$.

Integrate once more $$r(t)=e^C\ln(t)+D$$

Comment: Hmm, actually, its quite similar to answer but it is ln(t^2), I am trying to figure out where you possible made a mistake

Comment: @nany $\ln(t^2)=2\ln(t)=e^{\ln(2)}\ln(t)+0$. Put $C=\ln(2)$ and $D=0$.